# How to strip HTML tags correctly in PHP?

Tags: php, xss

I am trying to find a working way to strip HTML tags from a string in PHP. I know about strip_tags as well as filter_var (and I'm in the process of playing with filters for the latter) but I would appreciate any pointers at this stage.

The issue is this:

- strip_tags strips mostly as expected, with the exception of incomplete 'tags' such as `<test` which gets stripped even though it's not a tag (at most potentially). In this case I would like to either leave it as is or strip just the < - or perhaps ignore non-standard HTML tags
- filter_var, so far, can either html encode things or strip them the same way as `strip_tags` but I haven't yet found an in-between way.

Bonus: `voku/anti-xss` seems to correctly identify tags but it's bent on encoding them rather than removing them

Comment: If you're specifically meaning the XSS protection aspect, you can't ignore `htmlspecialchars`, though it's not removing tags...

Comment: http://htmlpurifier.org could be an option, but it probably requires a good amount of configuration.

Comment: @LarsStegelitz in this instance, XSS is secondary. Voku does a good job of mixing what htmlspecialchars does + some cleaning, but the cleaning is targeted at attributes.

Comment: @CBroe indeed, I looked at that before, but you're right, it does require a good amount of configuration. Basically I'd like to blacklist all standard HTML tags while purifier is aimed at cleaning the minimum required to provide XSS protection *and* keep the output standard :(